# Core Data objects modified attributes not updated immediately in tableview and not saved

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

This app uses ARC and Core Data with a SQLite database. Developed with Xcode 4.6 on OSX 10.8. The database contains many entities, several of them in a parent/child relationship. Everything fine except for the situation involving two entities in a parent/child relationship, which differ from other entities because they contain numeric attributes which value results from mathematical operations performed on other attributes of these two entities.

The child entity contains attributes A, B and C (where C = A * B).
The parent entity contains attribute X (where X = sum of its children's C).

Data are presented in two NSTableView on the same view. I use bindings to populate the tables. When I click on a cell to modify B, C should get updated immediately in the same table, and X in the other table. When I add or remove a child, X should also be updated immediately.

There are two problems.

1. When I modify B, C is updated immediately but X is not. When I add or remove a child, X is not updated either. In order for X to be updated, I need to leave the record and select another one in the table (then I can see that the X of the previously selected record gets updated).
2. On quitting the app, modified values of C and X are not written in the database file.

What did I miss in my code ? Here are my managed object classes. I modified the attributes and class names to make it clearer.

```
// header of parent

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Child;
@interface Parent : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * parent_X;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *children;
@end

@interface Parent (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addChildrenObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeChildrenObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeChildren:(NSSet *)values;
@end


// implementation of parent

#import "Parent.h"
@implementation Parent
@dynamic parent_X;
@dynamic children;
- (void)addChildrenObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {
    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:value];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:s];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"children"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:s];
}
- (void)removeChildrenObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {
    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:value];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:s];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"children"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:s];
}
- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)values {
    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:values];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:s];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"children"] addObject:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:s];
}
- (void)removeChildren:(NSSet *)values {
    NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:values];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:s];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"children"] removeObject:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"children" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:s];
}
- (NSDecimalNumber *)parent_X {
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"children.@sum.child_C"];
}
@end


// header of child

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Parent;
@interface Child : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * child_A;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * child_B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * child_C;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Parent *parent;
@end


// implementation of child

#import "Child.h"
#import "Parent.h"
@implementation Child
@dynamic child_A;
@dynamic child_B;
@dynamic child_C;
@dynamic parent;
- (void)awakeFromInsert {
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    [self setValue:@50.00f forKey:@"child_A"];
    [self setValue:@1.00f forKey:@"child_B"];
} 
-(NSDecimalNumber *)child_C {
    return [[self child_A] decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[self child_B]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems like you did not save to `CoreData` after you add or remove objects. I'm not sure about Xcode 4.6, but in 4.6.3, Xcode automatically populates the following method:

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Does yours have it and you just forgot to call it? If you don't have that populated, you will need to add it to save your changes to `CoreData`.

Or, you could simply call `- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error` from your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: It is Xcode 4.6.3 and the only method it generates automatically even when selecting Core Data for the project is this one:

    - (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        
        if (![[self managedObjectContext] commitEditing]) {
            NSLog(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing before saving", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        }
        
        if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry for wrong display here, don't know how to display code properly in a comment.

I've added your method to the AppDelegate but how exactly do I call/apply it in the managed object class? Thanks